# is there a way to only allow one type of input, such as only floats, ints to come from the input() call?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**so in this case, is there a way to only allow integers to pass onto the if statements, instead of raising a ValueError?**

```
import random
import string

def password(input):
    letters = string.ascii_letters
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(input))


while True:

    print("welcome to daniel's password generator!")
    length = int(input("how long do you want your password to be?: "))


    if length == 1:
        print("your newly generated password is " + password(1))

    elif length == 2:
        print("your newly generated password is " + password(2))

    elif length == 3:
            print("your newly generated password is " + password(3))

    elif length == 4:
        print("your newly generated password is " + password(4))

    elif length == 5:
        print("your newly generated password is " + password(5))

    elif length == 6:
        print("your newly generated password is " + password(6))
    else:
        print("unknown error!")
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `print("your newly generated password is " + password(length))` ? You don't need the ifs

Comment: you may use a `try` and `except` block inside a `do while` `loop` and exit only if you get a correct input.

Comment: Well, if you don't want a ValueError to be raised, and you also don't want the `if` statements to be reached, what **do** you want to happen?

Comment: The result if `input` is **always a `str`**.

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can’t force the `input()` to accept a type, it always return a string, then you have to handle it, you can use a loop, that ask until the content is numeric.
- Also you don't need `if`s, just use `length` variable
- you may use `random.sample` to make multiple choices

```
def password(length):
    return ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters , length))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("welcome to daniel's password generator!")
    while True:
        value = ""
        while not value.isnumeric():
            value = input("how long do you want your password to be?: ")
        length = int(value)
        print("your newly generated password is " + password(length))
```

Comment: There is also no need for the generator, just use `random.sample`: `return ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters, length))`

Comment: @DeepSpace I did not look the method, just past